# Vue3 use component from node_modules

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, node-modules

I'm trying to use a component from a node module I installed in Vue3, but it won't work.

I used:
`npm install --save vue-slick-carousel`

**my component**

```
<template>
   <div>
     <VueSlickCarousel :arrows="true" :dots="true">
       <div>1</div>
       <div>2</div>
       <div>3</div>
       <div>4</div>
     </VueSlickCarousel>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueSlickCarousel from 'vue-slick-carousel'
import 'vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel.css'

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  components: {
    VueSlickCarousel
  }
}
</script>
```

It seems like components from the node_modules folder won't work in general, because I have tryed to use an other library. My own components from the src/components folder work perfectly.
I also tryed to register the component globally in my main.js file, but it also won't work.

In my browsers console I always get this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: this.$scopedSlots is undefined**

Can anyone help?

Comment: Based on your question title, you have a Vue 3 project. `vue-slick-carousel` is a Vue 2 component, so you can't use it in your Vue 3 project. The other components in your `node_modules` are likely Vue 2 components. If you prefer to use those components, you'll have to downgrade your project to Vue 2, or use the migration build.

Comment: Thanks, I did not noticed that.
Well, I have to find a module for Vue3 then